# Write sql results to csv using Python

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, csv

I have a list of sql commands and I want to write their results to a csv file (every command's results in a different column). I managed to write the results to a csv file but unfortunately it always start writing from the first column. This is my code:

```
for command in sql_files:
    fd = open(command, 'r')
    sql_file = fd.read()
    fd.close()
    excel = open('output_file.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(excel)
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql_file)
    except:
        print "Error executing the file"
    writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cursor.description])  # heading row
    writer.writerows(cursor.fetchall())
```

For example for the following queries:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_users
SELECT age FROM tbl_costumers
```

The file would look like that:

```
 id | age
----------
 1  | 15
 2  | 20
```

Comment: You need to open the csv file in append mode `excel = open('output_file.csv', 'a')`

Comment: It adds the results in the same columns one after another.

Comment: A visual might be helpful here. A SQL usually command outputs a table, (sometimes a scalar, sometimes nothing). What does your result set(s) look like? How do they fit into a column?

Comment: I added an example to the question.